# Checking for success of fwrite in C, perror

Tags: c, fwrite

With fwrite returning the number of successful elements written to the file, by saying:

```
if (!(fwrite(...))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failure");
    //perror(???)  I sometimes see code that says perror here and I don't know 
    //exactly what this does.
}
```

Does this check for successful writing to the file?  Are there other things to worry about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, not quite. `fwrite` returns the number of elements successfully written; you need to check this against the number of elements you intended to write i.e. those you passed in argument to fwrite.

What you've done checks that some elements have been written.

Here's a reference for [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/).

> Interprets the value of the global
>   variable errno into a string and
>   prints that string to stderr (standard
>   error output stream, usually the
>   screen), optionaly preceding it with
>   the custom message specified in str.
>   errno is an integral variable whose
>   value describes the last error
>   produced by a call to a library
>   function. The error strings produced
>   by perror depend on the developing
>   platform and compiler. If the
>   parameter str is not a null pointer,
>   str is printed followed by a colon (:)
>   and a space. Then, whether str was a
>   null pointer or not, the generated
>   error description is printed followed
>   by a newline character ('\n'). perror
>   should be called right after the error
>   was produced, otherwise it can be
>   overwritten in calls to other
>   functions.

Comment: It's not necessary to compare `fwrite` against the number of elements if you arrange to always call it with `1` element of size `len`. Then the possible return values are just 0 and 1, with 0 indicating any failure and 1 indicating success.

Answer (score 3):

Your code might not check for errors properly. Use

```
if (fwrite(ptr, size, num, f) != num) {
    // An error occurred, handle it somehow
}
```

Comment: @mctylr: Wrong. `fwrite` cannot handle `EAGAIN` or `EINTR` at all. They will set the error indicator for the stream, and there's no way to resume writing without possibly getting lost or duplicate data (due to not knowing the state of the buffer). If you want to use interrupting signals or want to setup a file as nonblocking, stdio is generally not usable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `explain_fwrite()`, `explain_errno_fwrite`, ... from `libexplain`.

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_fwrite) explains:

> The `explain_fwrite` function is used to obtain an explanation of an error returned by the `fwrite(3)` system call. The least the message will contain is the value of `strerror(errno)`, **but usually it will do much better, and indicate the underlying cause in more detail.**
>
> The errno global variable will be used to obtain the error value to be decoded.
>
> This function is intended to be used in a fashion similar to the following example (the man-page was wrong here, as correctly pointed out by [@puchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404949/puchu) in the comment below. I corrected the code to address the issue):
>
> ```
> if (fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, fp) < nmemb)
> {
>     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", explain_fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, fp));
>     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
> }
> ```

**Caveat:** This method is not thread-safe.

Comment: fwrite returns `size_t`. `size_t` is unsigned value. It is not possible to `< 0`.

Comment: @puchu: Thanks. You are right. The man-page was wrong. Please see the corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux man page of fwrite

> fread()  and  fwrite()  return the number of items successfully read or
>   written (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error  occurs, or
>   the  end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or
>   zero).

so you need to compare with what is expected return value.

<strike>In many cases you may need to check for `errno` equal to `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`, in which case you normally want to retry the write request, while in other cases you want to handle short writes gracefully.</strike>

For fwrite, on a *short write* (where less than your entire data was written) you can check feof() and/or ferror() to see if the stream is returning and end-of-file, EOF, such as if a PIPE was closed, or if the stream has its error inducator flag set.

Comment: See my comment on your other comment. Retrying like you say will result in repeated failure and/or data corruption.

Comment: Yes, I did bork it, and I've striked out my original mistake. A program may attempt to call `fwrite()` after calling `clearerr()` safely, checking again for continued error/failure/EOF, in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
STRERROR(3)            FreeBSD Library Functions Manual            STRERROR(3)

NAME
     perror, strerror, strerror_r, sys_errlist, sys_nerr — system error mes‐
     sages

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdio.h>

     void
     perror(const char *string);

     ...

DESCRIPTION
     ...

     The perror() function finds the error message corresponding to the cur‐
     rent value of the global variable errno (intro(2)) and writes it, fol‐
     lowed by a newline, to the standard error file descriptor.  If the argu‐
     ment string is non‐NULL and does not point to the null character, this
     string is prepended to the message string and separated from it by a
     colon and space (“: ”); otherwise, only the error message string is
     printed.

...

STANDARDS
     The perror() and strerror() functions conform to ISO/IEC 9899:1999
     (“ISO C99”).  ...
```